# Why is my C# code block looking bland without syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, bug

Just yesterday, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70581121/1977871) and all the C# code blocks look bland without any syntax highlighting. See the screenshot of that below.

[image: Stack Overflow question C# question looking bland]

However, when I [look at my earlier question I asked a few days earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70565030/1977871) it looks perfectly fine.

[image: Stack Overflow question C# question looking fine]

Were you able to notice the contrast? What am I missing? Is it happening only on my machine? Or some bug?

I place both the Google Chrome windows side by side and they look as follows.

[image: Stack Overflow question C# question looking bland on one question and then fine on another]

Comment: syntax highlighting happens in two cases: you add the language tag to the question or you specify the language in your code fencing

Comment: What is code fencing?

Comment: Three backticks beginning and end of code block. Since you are using tab/4 spaces for code block, I added `<!-- language-all: lang-cs -->` to highlight all code blocks

Comment: The only tag you have on the question is [[tag:ef-core-6.0]] which doesn't have a language for syntax highlighting associated with it. compare with [[tag:c#]] (scroll all the way to the bottom).

Comment: The canonical is *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)* - e.g. *"Why isn't my code being highlighted correctly?"*